# How to update a D3 pie chart

Tags: d3.js, pie-chart

http://jsfiddle.net/z25SU/

I'm sorry, I realize there's tons of material on how to do this, and I've been though a few tutorials and looked though several of the official gists (like [this one](https://gist.github.com/mbostock/1346395)), but I still can't figure this out.

As you'll see in my jsfiddle, the chart renders with the first set of data fine - but the chart doesn't change at all when I click the update button.

The update method *does* fire, and the paths' "d" values *are* updated (as confirmed by watching those elements in Firebug) - it's just that the paths' new "d" values are the same as the old ones.

What do I need to do differently here? I've been slamming my head against this wall for hours now, trying every different thing the docs and tutorials have said - I just can't figure it out.

Thanks!

Also, here's the update method - someone will probably spot the issue without even having to look at the fiddle...

```
function updateData(dataset){
    //console.info(dataset);

    // Set Data
    var allSlices = slicesGroup
            .selectAll(".slice")
                .data(pie(dataset));

    // Create New Slices
    var newSlices = allSlices
            .enter()
            .append("g")
                .attr("class", "slice");

    newSlices
        .append("g")
            .attr("class", "outer")
            .append("path");

    newSlices
        .append("g")
            .attr("class", "inner")
            .append("path");

    // Update All Slices
    allSlices
        .selectAll(".outer")
            .selectAll("path")
                .attr("d", outerArc);

    allSlices
        .selectAll(".inner")
            .selectAll("path")
                .attr("d", innerArc);

    //console.log(newSlices);
    //console.log(allSlices);

    // Remove Old Slices
    allSlices.exit().remove();
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is related to your nested data structure.  Your new data is getting succesfully joined to your "slice" `<g>` elements, but not to your "inner" and "outer" `<g>` elements and the `<path>` elements themselves.

The fix is simple but non-intuitive.  Replace `allSlices.selectAll(".inner").selectAll("path")` with `allSlices.select(".inner").select("path")` and the same for the "outer" group.

http://jsfiddle.net/z25SU/1/

With `selection.select()` [the selected element inherits the updated data from the parent](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-select), versus in `.selectAll()` any existing data is not changed.  This important difference isn't very often emphasized in tutorials.  However, it makes sense -- if you are selecting many elements with `selectAll` they should each have their own data, it would not make sense to have them all receive the same value from the parent.

Comment: Arg! I knew it would be something simple :P Thank you for the answer, and especially the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the enter, update code. Here is the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/U97EY/).

You can use data2 or data3 in the update function.

```
// enter selection
var newSlices = allSlices.enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "slice");

// update selection
allSlices.append("g")
    .attr("class", "outer")
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", outerArc);

// update selection
allSlices.append("g")
    .attr("class", "inner")
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", innerArc);
```

Comment: This just adds new `<path>` elements on top of the old ones...  It could get very cluttered after multiple updates!

Comment: Yes, good point...i saw all the svg elements generated and not being familiar with the pie chart layout thought perhaps it was an artifact of it. Back to the drawing board...but too late for me...please feel free to clean up my mess with a new answer if you have some energy...thanks.

Comment: @FernOfTheAndes - Sorry, saw your comment at the exact moment as I posted mine and deleted mine :| Thank you for your answer! It does work, just not quite as intended...